# Force transaction to be with memo ID

Tags: stellar-sdk

Because we are exchange we use main account and we generate Id number as a memo that we send to the customer so we will know the transaction was from him.
we want to force the customer to add the memo , so if he does not add it the transaction will fail. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: In ripple we can use the destination tag as a required before making the transacion. Can we do the same for stellar ? As we found that stellar destination tag is the memo ID.

Comment: If you are using main account in exchange, Then exchange must send transaction on behalf of user by asking the `usedId` to whom user wants to send `asset`. So there is no way to validate `memo` in a transaction.

Comment: Ohh, so that means that this is something that the exchange must do as a middleware right?

Comment: Exacly, A user (front-end) makes a REST api call to your `exchange` by sending `userId` and then `exchange` must create transaction with `memo` as `userId` sent from REST api call and send this transaction to `Horizon`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it should works like ripple with the destination tag which can be forced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Federation server](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/anchor/3-federation-server.html) to do *most* of what you're asking.

If you have user `user_1` and your app is hosted at a site called `my-site.com`, then you can host your own federated server to work a little like a DNS server whereby the exchange can call the [resolveAddress](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/FederationServer.html#resolveAddress) method to get the address for that persons account.

So, by calling `resolveAddress('user_1*my-site.com')`, the exchange can expect to get a response along the lines of:

```
{
  "stellar_address": "user_1*my-site.com",
  "account_id": "GAIGZHHWK3REZQPLQX5DNUN4A32CSEONTU6CMDBO7GDWLPSXZDSYA4BU",
  "memo_type": "text",
  "memo": "user_1"
}
```

Here the `account_id` can be a shared *custodial account* or a unique account for that user. By setting the `memo` we can, of course, tell who the transaction was by/for.

Note: The federation server is a very simple protocol, so you can easily send a dynamic response where the `memo` field is a generated token.

Take for example this response:

```
{
  "stellar_address": "user_1*my-site.com",
  "account_id": "GAIGZHHWK3REZQPLQX5DNUN4A32CSEONTU6CMDBO7GDWLPSXZDSYA4BU",
  "memo_type": "text",
  "memo": "ABC123XYZ"
}
```

This second method allows you to hide the identity of the user on the ledger, as the only identifiable thing that will be recorded is `ABC123XYZ`. Only your systems, and the exchange performing the transaction will know the identity of the user.

The only caveat is that someone can still send a trusted asset to your `account_id` with a random memo, or no memo at all. I don't believe you can prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Method using [SEP-0007](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0007.md) to build a payment request using either [Operation TX](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0007.md#operation-tx) or [Operation PAY](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0007.md#operation-pay).

I have used the [Operation PAY](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0007.md#operation-pay) method to build a URI with a randomly generated MEMO_ID included in the URI:
`web+stellar:pay?destination=<DESTINATION_ADDR>&amount=[AMOUNT_CURR]&memo=<CUSTOM_MEMO_ID>`

This has the added benefit of forcing the use of MEMO_ID and functionality of paying wherever the customer feels most comfortable signing a transaction; the URI can be packaged into a QR-Code or create a link that should be read by a wallet that recognizes it (for example, Keybase on phone and/or PC).

[Operation TX](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0007.md) has more functionality by allowing a Transaction Envelope to be attached to the URI.